# Dart create instance using super class object

Tags: dart

Is it possible to construct an instance of a class with an instance of its super class without calling every field one by one ( in the below code,  I call `bar.name` )?

When I do, Foo foo = bar, I get

```
Instance of 'Bar': type 'Bar' is not a subtype of type 'Foo'
```

However, Foo extends bar

```
void main() {
 Bar bar = Bar('bar');
  Foo foo2 = Foo(null, bar.name); // Works but need to call every field 
  print(foo2.name);

  Foo foo = bar; // How to make this work ?
}
class Bar{
  final String name;
  Bar(this.name);
}
class Foo extends Bar{
  final int age;
  Foo(this.age, String name) :super(name);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want do to that?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible beacause it has no sens. `Foo` is a `Bar` (it extends `Bar`), but a `Bar` is not a `Foo`. So you can't assign it to a `Foo`.

Indeed, as `Foo` extends `Bar`, there are things missing in `Bar` that are present in `Foo`.

Back to your original question, if you want to create a `Foo` without `age` you can do something like that :

```
class Foo extends Bar{
  final int age;
  Foo(this.age, String name) :super(name);

  factory Foo.withoutAge(String name) => Foo(null, name);
}

void main() {
  Foo foo2 = Foo.withoutAge('bar'); 
  print(foo2.name);
}
```